# How to apply the formula to each Row of Spark DataFrame in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
+------+----+---------+--------+--------+
|nodeId|ni  |type     |avg_ni  |std_ni  |
+------+----+---------+--------+--------+
|     1|   1|        0|     0.5|  0.7071|
|     0|   0|        0|     0.5|  0.7071|
|     2|   0|        2|     0.0|     0.0|
|     3|   0|        4|  0.6667|  1.1547|
|     4|   2|        4|  0.6667|  1.1547|
|     5|   0|        4|  0.6667|  1.1547|
+------+----+---------+--------+--------+
```

I want to apply the formula `(ni - avg_ni) / std_ni` to each Row.

I tried it this way, but it does not work:

```
df.map(x => (x("ni")-x("avg_ni")/x("std_ni"))).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `withColumn` or `select`:

```
df.select(($"ni" - $ "avg_ni") / $"std_ni")
```

optionally with conversion

```
df.select(($"ni" - $ "avg_ni") / $"std_ni").as[Double]
```

Comment: What if the formula would be more complicated? Is it possible to use UDF?

Comment: @Markus, this way should be more efficient and faster than using a udf function